# How to modify primary key in MySQL because, I forget auto_increment field?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1068

```
mysql> alter table users
-> modify user_id int primary key not null auto_increment;
```

> ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined

Comment: Is there any data in that table?

Comment: Show current CREATE TABLE.